# td width percentage of table and table header not behaving correctly?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-table, width

I'm trying to create a soccer schedule table that shows the team and duration like such in this plnkr I made: http://plnkr.co/edit/osuQiVZ2cFKFhbEXylA9?p=preview

I'm trying to make it so the td element (which is duration of game in minutes) for each team is the width percentage of the total time (24 hour period) -- At the same time having the td element appear to start at the appropriate interval in relationship to the 24 hour period th.

I think i'm on the right track getting the width% by dividing the duration in minutes by how many minutes in a day (1440). However I do not know how the td% adjusts itself to the parent element? Is it the tr element width or the table width that the td is adjusting itself off of?

As you can see in the plnkr I'm having trouble scaling the th element so I tried adding two span elements inside 2nd th but that didn't work well as you can see.

Could anyone explain how I might be able to think about working with td% in this case inside the table element?

```
<table class="table table-default">
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            <span>00:00</span>
            <span class="pull-right">24:00</span>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="team in soccerSchedule">
            <td width="100px">
        {{team.team}}
            </td>
            <td class="bg-primary" width="{{widthPercent(secondsToMinutes(team.duration))}}%">
              {{secondsToMinutes(team.duration)}} Minutes Long | Start Time: {{team.startTime}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then my angular controller

```
   angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.soccerSchedule = [
    {team: 'lightning', duration: 18000, startTime:"12:00"}, 
    {team: 'thunder', duration: 18000, startTime:"12:00"},
    {team: 'force', duration: 18000, startTime:"18:00"},
    {team: 'tigers', duration: 18000, startTime:"14:00"},
  ];  

  $scope.widthPercent = function(durationInMinutes){
        return ((durationInMinutes / 1440) * 100);
  };

  $scope.secondsToMinutes = function(seconds){
        return (seconds / 60);
  };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are trying to achieve (different widths) goes against the tabular way of presenting data.

This can be easily achieved by leaving the columns untouched and adding an extra div inside each column which would represent your timespan. And by using the ng-style directive, you dynamically give it the value based on your calculations.

```
<td>
    <div class="bg-primary" ng-style="{width : ( widthPercent(secondsToMinutes(team.duration)) + '%' ) }">
       {{secondsToMinutes(team.duration)}} Minutes Long | Start Time: {{team.startTime}}
    </div>
</td>
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6bPGrqpsJ13SOHTYWskP?p=preview

I've also changed your duration values so you can see it working.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this but was thinking about using a span instead of a div to achieve the same affect. Now, if I wanted to have the start time match up with the th element (like have them indented from the left) would I achieve the same effect but with the left-margin property on the div?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. Have it look like in the original plunker that you provided? If that's it, try giving the second <th> a fixed width and the rest is going to align accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that table columns have the same width.  You can't vary the width of a cell within a row.  Instead, you can create many tables.  In this case, I'm putting a new 1-row table in each row of the parent table, but there are other ways to achieve it as well.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Cc1an7P3rRteeW1LAxsC?p=preview

```
   <tr ng-repeat="team in soccerSchedule">
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
              <td width="{{100 -  widthPercent(secondsToMinutes(team.duration))}}%">
          {{team.team}}
              </td>
              <td class="bg-primary" width="{{widthPercent(secondsToMinutes(team.duration))}}%">
                {{secondsToMinutes(team.duration)}} Minutes Long | Start Time: {{team.startTime}}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I see. Could you explain how the width% is adjusting to what? If I want to make my width expand to 100% of the th headers (ie: match the time from 00:00 to 24:00, how could I approach this?)